# backbone collection fetch does not run anything inside the success call, but fetches all ok

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection that fetches with this line:

```
console.info("before fetching drivesCollection");
this.drivesCollection.fetch({
  success: function() {
    console.info("inside fetching drivesCollection");
  },
  error: function(collection, response, options) {
     console.log('ERROR fetching drivesCollection ');
  }
});
console.info("after fetching drivesCollection");
```

the fetching works as expected, and the error callback never get's called. I can see all models (200+) inside the collection afterwards. The problem is that anything inside the success function is not being called. I need to put a function there.

I tried to debug why the `success` function is being skipped somehow using the `parse` function of the collection definition as this:

```
parse: function(response){
    console.log('starting parsing of drivesCollection');
    console.log(response.length);
    console.log(response);
    return response
```

},

it works as expected, and returns valid values that are inserted into the collection...

Any ideas why my `success` function never runs?

Comment: Can you tell us what gets printed (if anything at all) to console when you do: `this.drivesCollection.fetch().always(function(){ console.log.apply(console, arguments) })`

Comment: nothing. this doesn't produce any output on the console. (I replaced my fetch with everything inside for yours)

Comment: yes, I see the collection in the network tab in safari. As I mentioned, The collection is fully accesible in the drivesCollection object. It's like it was parsed correctly.

Comment: Can't think of anything. Still perhaps I'd mention... try to clear the browser cache?

Comment: I already tried that. I also tried on different machines (mac and win) and each on different browsers (chrome, safari, firefox).

Comment: I face the same issue

Comment: Do you have validation on the models?

Comment: @idbehold I don't have validation at client side. should I? will it help? to debug this strange behavior?

Comment: Validations in your models would probably just get in the way at this point. Have you tried adding `error` and `complete` callbacks to the `fetch` options? Is the server using the right Content-Type in the response? Are you using the latest jQuery and Backbone?

Comment: @muistooshort I had indeed backbone 0.9. I updated to the newest and this misbehavior is GONE! Post an answer, I'll select it as the solving answer, for future reference.

Comment: Let me try and figure out what changed between 0.9 and now that might cause your problem. If I can't explain what went wrong then I don't understand the problem, if I don't understand then I don't feel justified in offering an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I think of is:

1) Your server isn't sending the right header information concerning content type in which the quick fix would be to force the use of getting JSON data by adding the parameter

```
this.drivesCollection.fetch({
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() {
    console.info("inside fetching drivesCollection");
  }
});
```

2) OR, you're mistakenly are using a Backbone.Model to fetch collections and not a Backbone.Collection (I've made that mistake a few times)